# how to find or decrypt the url of javascript:void(0)

Tags: javascript, html, anchor, href, void

well, I just downloaded a code from internet and it has

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="action">login</a>
```

when i click on it, it shows a pop up.
I want to use that pop on any other button , but does no know how to do that. can any one please explain me how it can be done or how the current given line is working.
I am just new to this, so please dont be mad if it is a stupid question.
Thank you

Answer (score 5):

`javascript:void(0)` returns `undefined`, so the link does not actually lead to anywhere when clicked and the normal `<a>` element behavior is suppressed. That means there's a click handler set up on the element that handles showing the popup. This click handler is found somewhere else in the code.

I'm assuming that the click handler is associated with the `action` class, so if you attached `class="action"` to another element, you'll probably see the popup.

Comment: ok, so you are saying that in here <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="action">login</a> , anchor tag is not the one causing the popup to appear but the class action is causing it, right?

Comment: @ShahidRafiq exactly - whenever an anchor tag links to javascript:void(0) or # etc the link itself isn't taking you anywhere, rather it relies on the event listener attached to it

Answer (score 1):

To create "pop ups" (actually known as alerts), you use the following code:

```
 alert(yourStringMessageHere);
```

The javascript: part of the code you are showing simply tells the HTML parser that when the hyperlink is clicked, the following JavaScript should be executed. void(0) is asking for the expression 0 to be evaluated and since 0 is another way of expressing false, the expression essentially winds up causing nothing to happen, which when added to a hyperlink's href attribute is sometimes desirable.  This code does not cause a pop up to appear. If you are getting one, it is because of something else.

Lastly, including JavaScript into html in this way is strongly discouraged as it is bad form and can lead to code that is difficult to read and maintain. JavaScript should be separated from HTML.

Comment: I think he means he's getting a new window showing an HTML page, not an alert box

Comment: Even still, the code provided isn't making that happen. The anchor's click won't do anything with what is shown.

Comment: No, I agree (especially your comment about separating HTML and JS) - but it might be best not to confuse him by assuming he means alert when he does actually mean a new window

Comment: ok, so you are saying that in here <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="action">login</a> , anchor tag is not the one causing the popup to appear but the class action is causing it, right?

Comment: @ChrisW I don't think that it's clear whether he meant new window or alert. I took "pop up" to mean alert. But, again that is being caused by something other than the code he showed.

Comment: @ShahidRafiq Something else is causing it, but we can't know if it is the class unless you show us all the code.